# How do I check in VueJS if a user has a specific word in their nickname?

Tags: vue.js

I need to do the following: the user registers on the site enters his nickname, I need to check the nickname for any given word. In php, I did it just with the function `if (strstr (strtolower ($ user-> username), strtolower (my word)))`, but how can I implement this in Vuejs?

Like, if he has a given word in his nickname, display the text "Denied" to him.

Answer (score 2):

Try JavaScript function `includes()`:

```js
var username = "yrbet";

username.includes("bet") // => TRUE
```

EDIT:
To resolve the problem with the font case, try this:

```js
var username = "yrbet";

username.toLowerCase().includes("bet".toLowerCase()) // => TRUE
```

Comment: thanks for reply! now in console i has error: `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"`

Comment: That means the value is not set. Are you sure the variable has value you are expecting?